# Sum the results of SQL query in same Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to sum the results of two columns in the third column

```
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID,
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS active, 
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS idle,

FROM time A join ttld.login B on A.EmpID=B.username 
WHERE DATE = '01-15-2019' GROUP BY A.EmpID
```

The third column should be the total of the active and idle numbers I have tried below query but due to my little to no knowledge I'm not able to run it

```
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID,
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS active, 
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS idle,

SUM(CASE WHEN State = ('idle','active') THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS Total_of_active_and_Idle

FROM time A join ttld.login B on A.EmpID=B.username 
WHERE DATE = '01-15-2019' GROUP BY A.EmpID
```

Comment: You want `in` rather than `=` . . . or `= any ()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below- you need to add  in ('idle','active')

```
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID,
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS active, 
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS idle,

SUM(CASE WHEN State in ('idle','active') THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS Total_of_active_and_Idle

FROM time A join ttld.login B on A.EmpID=B.username 
WHERE DATE = '01-15-2019' GROUP BY A.EmpID,A.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `IN` clause or `= any ()`, however `MySQL` has shorthand instead of `case . .  end` :

```
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID,
       SUM( State = 'active' ) AS active, 
       SUM( State = 'idle' ) AS idle,
       SUM( State = any('idle','active') ) AS Total_of_active_and_Idle
FROM time A JOIN
     ttld.login B 
     ON A.EmpID = B.username 
WHERE DATE = '01-15-2019' 
GROUP BY A.EmpID;
```